# How to store sensitive datas with NodeJS without storing private key in plain text?

Tags: node.js, security, password-protection

[dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) is recommended to store local configuration with [strict separation of config from code](https://12factor.net/config). However, it stores a private key as plain text in the `.env` file.

Also, [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module somehow needs to deal with plain text password.

Is there a way to store a password which can be deciphered with a system-dependent  algorithm, so if the encrypted password is stolen, it would still requires to know the source system features?

Comment: At a second glance, it seems to just put the issue some extra steps away... An intruder could just retrieve local datas to decipher the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no. Think of it this way, you need the text, in some way, to do some task. How do you normally keep text like this private? Hashing, however if it is a 1-way hash algorithm this is useless, as you dont want to validate the hash but rather gather the contents of said hash, if it is a hash and salt algorithm where you can retrieve the data, you are only adding extra steps for the perpetrator. Storing it in a `.env` file is the safest route to go, make sure to add it to `.gitignore` or your own vcs ignore file, optionally disable IDE local file tracking if its available.